# Populate radio buttons from object properties using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to set radio buttons matching the values to the properties from an object that is being returned and have the button checked according to the values but my code is not working for me.

I have the HTML with the radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="subject1" value="0" checked />
<input type="radio" name="subject1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="subject1" value="2" />

<input type="radio" name="subject2" value="0" checked />
<input type="radio" name="subject2" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="subject2" value="2" />

<input type="radio" name="subject3" value="0" checked />
<input type="radio" name="subject3" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="subject3" value="2" />
```

I am returning an object:

```
obj = { CustomObjectKey: 2, subject1: "2", subject2: "0", subject3: "1", subject4: "0", ..... }
```

I am trying to set the radio buttons and check them according to the data that is coming back. All values are set at 0 in the beginning but will need to change according to the properties and values.

I have my Jquery script as so:

```
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
$("input[name='+key+'][value='+value+']").prop('checked', true);
});
```

So for subject1 the radio button with value "2" should be checked

But my radio buttons just stay at "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research and testing I found my solution which included updating the JQuery Library to 2.2.0.min.js as @Nadimul De Cj suggested and modifying the code as such:

```
$.each(user_pref, function(key, value){
$("input:radio[name="+key+"][value="+value+"]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

which made the code work.

Answer (score 0):

Your string concatenation in `each` is wrong. Replace `double quotes(")` with `single quotes(')`.

```
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    $('input[name='+key+'][value='+value+']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

**Full Code**

```js
var obj = { CustomObjectKey: 2, subject1: "2", subject2: "0", subject3: "1", subject4: "0" };

$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    $('input[name='+key+'][value='+value+']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="subject1" value="0" checked />
<input type="radio" name="subject1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="subject1" value="2" />

<input type="radio" name="subject2" value="0" checked />
<input type="radio" name="subject2" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="subject2" value="2" />

<input type="radio" name="subject3" value="0" checked />
<input type="radio" name="subject3" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="subject3" value="2" />
```

Comment: Changing the quotes didn't work me. The strange thing is that in the FF Console, the only way it evaluates the Jquery is when I tested the way I had it. using the double quotes around the Jquery function but single when passing the values

so either all double or single quotes didn't have any effect but testing the Jquery in the console this would actually change the value (I used the static values to see if the code would change the check box)

    $("input[name='subject1'][value='2']").prop('checked', true)

Comment: But code snippet in my answer is working fine. @dmcs14db

Comment: Yes it is that's why I am some what confused.

Maybe I should mention that "var obj" is actually being set by SSJS via the stringify function

I have to run some SSJS to pull the data but then pass it to the variable so that I can use it in the JQuery

it does pull the data from a database and puts it in to a array which I then 
    Write("var obj=" + Stringify(data) + ";");

However when I output the object to the console it gives me the object/properties as expected.

Comment: I think `JSON.parse(obj)` will solve your problem. @dmcs14db

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your single quotes (') to double quotes (") like below:

```
$("input[name="+key+"][value="+value+"]").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: @dmcs14db do you check your jquery file attached or not ... cdn < script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" ><script>

Comment: Yes I was first using a local version but I changed it to this version. I think I am missing something within the variable construct within the SSJS and how it returns the object because your fiddle works fine.

Comment: @dmcs14db .. if you dont mind .. can you please send me your hole code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I would if I could the issue is that the data is being called out of Salesforce so the SSJS is using some proprietary scripting to get the data out of the application then I use Stringify and pass it to the client via Write.

    Write("var obj= " + Stringify(data) + ";");

I think the issue is that it's a JS Object literal I think and for some reason doesn't. but I don't understand why the JSfiddle works with the Jquery but it doesn't work when I implement it nothing really is different except that the data is passed versus written out manually